# VosCast live streaming in android apps

Tags: android, android-studio, live-streaming, shoutcast

I'm developing an android application for a radio station, they have [this](http://station.voscast.com/52a87cd4114ca/) live streaming channel on VosCast, i want to put a live stream Button on the ActionBar, and let it stream from the URL when pressed. And of course stop when pressed again.

Anybody can help with that ?

Comment: have you found any good solution for this?Please tell me. I also want same thing